# Mysql Innodb engine status BACKGROUND THREAD

Tags: mysql, innodb

I got this output from `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`

```
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 2738330 1_second, 2738328 sleeps, 270109 10_second, 48276 background, 48238 flush
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 2743704
```

What does these terms mean? What is the unit(seconds or count) of these numbers?

PS: Couldn't find any explanation in Google!

Comment: I wouldn't call _"Couldn't find any explanation in Google!"_ a justification; you shouldn't be looking on Google; you should be looking in the manual.

Comment: Look at the line above what you showed.  As for what use the numbers are -- very little use to the average programmer.  If you are having performance problems, find the slowest query and let's discuss it.

Comment: I checked the manual already. _The srv_master_thread lines shows work done by the main background thread_ was the only information in the manual. @underscore_d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easly find this info in  mysql (or mariadb, or percona) manual

> BACKGROUND THREAD
>
> The srv_master_thread lines shows work done by the main background
>   thread.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-standard-monitor.html

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/diagnostics/innodb_show_status.html

```
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 1 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 11844 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 11844
```

> InnoDB has a master thread which performs background tasks depending
>   on the server state, once per second. If the server is under workload,
>   the master thread runs the following: performs background table drops;
>   performs change buffer merge, adaptively; flushes the redo log to
>   disk; evicts tables from the dictionary cache if needed to satisfy its
>   size limit; makes a checkpoint. If the server is idle: performs
>   background table drops, flushes and/or checkpoints the redo log if
>   needed due to the checkpoint age; performs change buffer merge at full
>   I/O capacity; evicts tables from the dictionary cache if needed; and
>   makes a checkpoint.

Comment: Thank you :) The second link is very helpful